# How to make anchor links jump to content when using bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap tabs and would like to create and anchor link that will cause the page to scroll immediately down to the content area when I click on the tabs. You can't see the need for an anchor on desktop but for mobile (refer to attachment), the user has to scroll down to see the content. Hence the need for an anchor link.

[image]

Markup:

```
<div class="collapse in" id="collapse1">
    <ul class="features nav nav-pills nav-stacked" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation">  <!-- feature tab menu #1 -->
            <a href="#overview" aria-controls="f1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" >
                overview
            </a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"> <!-- feature tab menu #2 -->
            <a href="#history" aria-controls="f2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                history
            </a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"> <!-- feature tab menu #3 -->
            <a href="#mission" aria-controls="f3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                mission & vision
            </a>
        </li>
        <!--
        <li role="presentation"> 
             <a href="#vision" aria-controls="f4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                 vision
             </a>
        </li>
        -->
        <li role="presentation"> <!-- feature tab menu #5 -->
             <a href="#values" aria-controls="f5" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                 values
             </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- overview content open -->
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active about-heading" id="overview">
    <!-- i want to set an anchor here --></a> <h4>overview</h4>
    <?php echo $content; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: So what is your question? I see a `<a href="#overview" ...` and `<div ... id="overview">` that should work fine. Anchors will go to ID as well as name attributes. Is it not working?

Comment: You only have to give the div which you wanna navigate to an id and put the id in the href of the anchor tag. For example, clicking `<a ref="#mission" aria-controls="f3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">mission & vision</a>` will bring you to the elemtn with id `mission`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If you look at the attached image, you would see that the content is not immediately visible when viewed on mobile. The user has to scroll down in order to see it. that's why i need to do an anchor link so that when user clicks on the tab, the page will show the relevant content and also scroll immediately down to the content itself.

Comment: So, are you asking us how to create the anchor link, or have you tried to create one but its not working?

Comment: If you look at this page - http://zaaroinfotechsolutions.com/zaarodemo/longbeach/corporate/ - you can see that the tabs *overview, history, mission & vision, values) are working fine; they are showing their respective content when clicked. However, if you view it on mobile, you will notice that the content is partially hidden at the bottom. What I want is for the page to scroll down to the content (like an anchor link) when user clicks on the tab. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I can see that it's working now. Right?